# Change Android TabWidget bottom bar color

Tags: android, tabwidget

How do I change the color of the bottom bar for TabWidget?  I have successfully changed the tab background color but the bottom bar is still grey/orange and I couldn't find any info in the Android doc and source regarding this.  Thanks.

Comment: have a look at this http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136 @Kenny Ma you will get an idea

Comment: I've seen this before and just read through it again but didn't see anything about the bottom strip.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that "bottom bar" refers to the optional horizontal line that separates the tabs and the content.  Take a look at the various tabStrip attributes described in [the TabWidget API doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html).  You can set different drawables for the left and right parts of the strip.

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried using "android:tabStripLeft" and "android:tabStripRight" but I'm getting "No resource identifier found for attribute 'tabStripRight' in package 'android'" error.  Any idea?

Comment: Solved.  Changing my build target from 2.1 to 2.2 solved the "no resource found..." problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See:

to enable/disable this line:
`tabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(boolean);`

to set drawable at left for this line:
`tabHost.getTabWidget().setLeftStripDrawable(drawable);`

to set resourse at left for this line
`tabHost.getTabWidget().setLeftStripDrawable(resId);`

to set drawable at right for this line: 
`tabHost.getTabWidget().setRightStripDrawable(drawable);`

to set resourse at right for this line:
`tabHost.getTabWidget().setRightStripDrawable(resId);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) { 
     int totalTabs = tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();
     for(int i=0;i<totalTabs;i++) {
        if(tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).isSelected()){
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selector); //selector xml for selected
            tabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(true);
            tabHost.getTabWidget().setRightStripDrawable(R.drawable.tab_strip_thin); 
            tabHost.getTabWidget().setLeftStripDrawable(R.drawable.tab_strip_thin);
        }
     }
    }
```